# Need help to make the first <select> option blank in php retrieving column in mySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, select

I have a good php script that works.  But I need to modify it so the first select option is blank.  Can anyone help?

```
<?php
// connect to MySQL
$query = "SELECT <col> FROM <table>";
$result = mysql_query($query);
?>
<select name="sel" id="sel">
<?php
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
echo "<option>{$row['<col>']}</option>";
}
?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you mean?

```
<?php
// connect to MySQL
$query = "SELECT <col> FROM <table>";
$result = mysql_query($query);
?>
<select name="sel" id="sel">
  <option value="-1"></option>
<?php
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
  echo "<option>{$row['<col>']}</option>";
}
?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just make it blank:

```
<?php
// connect to MySQL
$query = "SELECT <col> FROM <table>";
$result = mysql_query($query);
?>
<select name="sel" id="sel">
<option></option>
<?php
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
echo "<option>{$row['<col>']}</option>";
}
?>
</select>
```